# Jasmine tests not detecting jQuery internationalized constants

Tags: javascript, jquery, internationalization, jasmine

**Problem**: I am having an issue where I try to read constants from a `.properties` file, but its variables won't be defined within the scope of `it` unit tests. Execution of the below tests will print `1 Hello World!`, but not `2 Hello World!`. Jasmine is saying that `MY_CONSTANT` is not defined within the `print something` unit test, however it is defined in the `callback` in the call to `jQuery.i18n.properties(...)`.

**What seems to be happening**: the issue seems to be that the constants in `messages.properties` are being set in `beforeAll(...)` *after* the unit tests are run. I am seeing `console.log(...)` from unit tests print before the `1 Hello World!` in `jQuery.i18n.properties(...)`'s `callback` function. How can I force the tests to wait for asynchronous call in `beforeAll(...)` to finish first?

Simplified Jasmine test file (src/test/javascript/mySpec.js):

```
describe('Test for buttons and output in home page.', function() {
  beforeAll(function() {
    jQuery.i18n.properties({
      name : 'Messages',
      path : 'src/main/resources/bundle/',
      mode : 'both',
      language : 'en_US',
      async : true,
      callback: function() {
        console.log('1 ' + MY_CONSTANT);
      }
    });
  });
  beforeEach(function() {
    jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = 'src/test/javascript/fixture';
    loadFixtures('myFixture.html');
    $.holdReady(false);
  });
  it('print something.', function(){
    console.log('2 ' + MY_CONSTANT);
  });
});
```

Simplified properties file (src/main/resources/bundle/messages.properties):

```
MY_CONSTANT=Hello World!
```

P.S. this is a project that uses Java and jQuery. The Jasmine unit test currently runs purely using jQuery and Javascript. I am also running the tests using maven with `mvn jasmine:bdd`.

**More info**:

there is a file in the main directory that also calls `jQuery.i18n.properties`, `src/main/resources/assets/internationalization.js`, which is called with the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery.i18n.properties({
    name: 'Messages',
    path: 'bundle/',
    mode: 'both',
    language: 'en_US',
    async: true,
    callback: function() {
      initializeText();
    }
  });
});
```

`initializeText()` is basically a function that sets some necessary display texts by associating the properties with an HTML id, but it doesn't set `MY_CONSTANT` so the code shouldn't matter. I am posting this for the chance that it might matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I set `async: true`. When I removed `async: true`, the tests passed:

```
beforeAll(function() {
  jQuery.i18n.properties({
    name : 'Messages',
    path : 'src/main/resources/bundle/',
    mode : 'both',
    language : 'en_US',
    callback: function() {
      console.log('1 ' + MY_CONSTANT);
    }
  });
});
```

The documentation was actually in a github repository readme:
https://github.com/jquery-i18n-properties/jquery-i18n-properties